# Does running a jupyter notebook trigger any web traffic?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm a bit embarrased to even ask this, but I need to be 100% sure: Does basic usage of a jupyter notebook (running on localhost:8888) trigger any web traffic? I've found it surprisingly hard to find good info on this in the [docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just running localhost:8888, and accessing it from your own computer, then no you are not actually generating web traffic, since you can access it even when you have no internet connection.
There will still be traffic when you interact with the notebook, just not web traffic, I believe.