# Does Jupyter Notebook or Lab risk exposing data via the web?

Tags: jupyter

I’m very new to Jupyter and seeing that it is browser based. If I use Jupyter via Anaconda, does this mean that data is actually being sent out to the web for a notebook to work, or only that it is running via my browser software (but always locally)? I will be working with sensitive data and would like to understand any security issues connected to the Jupyter approach. Finally, are there any differences in this context between Jupyter Notebooks and Jupyter Lab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does running a jupyter notebook trigger any web traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803308/does-running-a-jupyter-notebook-trigger-any-web-traffic)

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I took the reply to mean that the default Jupyter settings involve a web browser but do not actually involve the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter Notebooks are, by default, only accessible from the computer they're running on. So if you're using a laptop and start a notebook up you'll be the only person who can access it.

From [their website](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html)-

> By default, a notebook server runs locally at 127.0.0.1:8888 and is accessible only from localhost. You may access the notebook server from the browser using http://127.0.0.1:8888.

It is possible to override that to share notebooks, but if you do you should [add authentication](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#securing-a-notebook-server) to prevent anyone from being able to access the information. Also you should keep in mind that anyone who can access the notebook can also run code on that machine, which has a lot of security implications.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I followed the full response except for the final sentence. If someone had notebook access after receiving authentication, which machine are they then able to run code on, and how could they run code that would be potentially malicious?

Comment: Lets say you launch a notebook on your local computer and gave someone else permission to access it. When that happens your computer is running the code, and the output is being sent to the browser. Since it runs as your user the other person will be able to access your files and run whatever they want on your machine.